# I want to make a discord bot so that it can take in 2 part commands. So if I said -count 5, my bot would say 6

Tags: javascript, discord

Just for clarification, I am doing this in javascript (a language I had no experience in until yesterday), as a sort of learning experience/"trial" to see if I like the language that much.

Comment: `So if I said -count 5, my bot would say 6` - why would it do that?

Comment: You need to explain the logic behind what you want a bit better. Right now it is unclear what you want to do.